# In which Mysql Type Should I save My News Field?

Tags: html, mysql, blogs

I am building a small blog system for adding news to my website and I want to know what is the most useful type to save the news in the database with the html format and get it from the database with its plain text format to show in the browser??

Comment: TEXT would be best suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll depend on how large the strings your storing are but most likely you'll want to go with the **Text datatype** (nonbinary version of Blob).

The general rule of thumb is to use VARCHAR up until 255 characters, then use Text.  Blob and Text both allow you to store huge string values without removing line endings.

For your use TinyText will most likely suffice.

You can read more information on them here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html